# Rust image::io::Reader: Permission Denied

Tags: rust

I'm trying to load some images into my fltk-rs app:

```
fltk = "1.0.1"
image = "0.23.14"
```

```rust
use fltk::{app, app::*, window::*, prelude::*, window::Window, button::*, group::*, image::*};
use std::fs;
use image::*; 
use image::io::Reader as ImageReader; 
//..
for x in cursor_paths.into_iter(){
        let mut but = Button::new(0,0,25,25,"");
        let sc = s.clone();
        let mut win_cl = win.clone();
        let img = ImageReader::open(x.unwrap().path().display().to_string()).unwrap().decode().unwrap();
        let bytes = img.clone().into_rgba8().into_vec();
        let rgb = fltk::image::RgbImage::new(&bytes, img.clone().width() as i32, img.clone().height() as i32, fltk::enums::ColorDepth::Rgba8).unwrap();
        let rgb_cl = rgb.clone();
        but.set_callback(move |_|{
            win_cl.clone().set_cursor_image(rgb.clone(), 0,0);
        });
        but.set_image(Some(rgb_cl))
}
//..
```

But doing so gives error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
value: Os { code: 5, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Access is denied." }', src\main.rs:31:78
```

Is this a OS issue? If so how might I fix it?

OS: Window 10
Editor: VSCode
Rust Version: 2018

Comment: Yes, this is an OS issue, not a Rust issue. Can you open the image by double clicking on it? Are you running your app in some kind of limited sandboxed environment? Is there an overzealous antivirus software in play?

Comment: No sandboxed env as far as I am aware. Using standard rustc. Never had a problem with antivirus before. Can open image via file browser properly.

Comment: Try printing `x.unwrap().path().display().to_string()` just to be sure that the image path is what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it appears that the relative path notation was causing the issue:

```rust
 let cursor_paths = fs::read_dir("/assets/cursors/").unwrap();
```

instead of:

```rust
let cursor_paths = fs::read_dir("./assets/cursors/").unwrap();
```