# Can't execute Kotlin scripts from Rust

Tags: windows, kotlin, rust

I'm trying to run `kotlinc` from within Rust on Windows. Here is a small snippet of my code:

```rust
let mut script_number: u32 = 0;
let script_path: String = format!("run/script-{script_number}.kts");

println!("Running Script: {script_number}");

let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
    .read(true)
    .write(true)
    .create(true)
    .open(script_path.clone())
    .expect("Could not create file");

file.write_all(
    self.editor
        .buffer()
        .expect("Couldn't read buffer.")
        .text()
        .as_bytes(),
)
.expect("Could not write to file");

let mut child = Command::new("./kotlinc")
    .arg("-script")
    .arg(script_path.clone())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .expect("Could not execute script");

let stdout = child.stdout.take().expect("Could not read output");

let lines = BufReader::new(stdout).lines();

for line in lines {
    println!("{}", line.unwrap());
}

script_number += 1;
```

I get the following output and error:

```
Running Script: 0

thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not execute script: Os { code: 5, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Access is denied." }', src\main.rs:265:30
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
             at /rustc/69f9c33d71c871fc16ac445211281c6e7a340943/library\std\src\panicking.rs:575      
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/69f9c33d71c871fc16ac445211281c6e7a340943/library\core\src\panicking.rs:65      
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/69f9c33d71c871fc16ac445211281c6e7a340943/library\core\src\result.rs:1791       
   3: enum2$<core::result::Result<std::process::Child,std::io::error::Error> >::expect<std::process::Child,std::io::error::Error>
             at /rustc/69f9c33d71c871fc16ac445211281c6e7a340943\library\core\src\result.rs:1070       
   4: gui_editor::App::launch
             at .\src\main.rs:260
   5: gui_editor::main
             at .\src\main.rs:291
   6: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<void (*)(),tuple$<> >
             at /rustc/69f9c33d71c871fc16ac445211281c6e7a340943\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:251  
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

I suspect it's that the file created does not have execute permissions, however, after scouring the internet I cannot seem to find a way that gives the file execute permissions. Some answers online reference a `mode` function however that function doesn't seem to exist when I try to run it.

Just for context, the `run` directory stores scripts that have been scheduled to run by the program, and both it and the `kotlinc` (a copy of the Kotlin compiler) directories are sibling directories of the Rust `src` directory.

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276504/rust-imageioreader-permission-denied

Comment: This worked in removing this error, however now I have another error. Here is some debug output along with the error at the very end: Running Script: 0 File { handle: 0x39c, path: "\\\\?\\D:\\Files\\Documents\\gui-editor\\script-0.kts" }

The current directory is D:\Files\Documents\gui-editor

File exists: true

thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not execute script: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the file specified." }', src\main.rs:271:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer after digging around in the kotlinc file. The file that needs to be run is `./kotlinc/bin/kotlinc.bat` i.e.:

```rust
std::process::Command::new("./kotlinc/bin/kotlinc.bat")
        .arg("-version")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("Could not execute script");
```